# Integrating Drupal into an existing site to manage comments

Tags: users, comments

I am involved in a project that wishes to post a wide range of products, and allows users to review these products. I don't want to use Drupal for the design, layout, etc. I am only interested in using Drupal for managing all of the user generated reviews. Is this integration possible, or recommended?

Could anyone please point me in the right direction for more information about the subject?

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question, and it probably depends on what your project is using other than Drupal, from what I hear there are some decent "hybrid" CMS options out there.

You can combine Drupal with [NodeJS](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodejs) or [AngularJS](https://www.drupal.org/project/angularjs).

Since you said you don't want Drupal for the design, that is called "[**headless/decoupled Drupal**](https://www.specbee.com/blogs/headless-drupal-enterprises-are-choosing-decoupled-drupal-websites)".

Here is some more information: [Headless Drupal: The What, Why and How](https://buttercms.com/blog/headless-drupal-the-what-why-and-how)